# Is there any way to archive and recover entire page (with entire html, css, img, js, ...) using selenium chromedriver on ubuntu?

Tags: selenium, web, selenium-chromedriver

I'm looking for a way to archive the entire state of webpage, for the purpose of archiving the webpage.

Actually, what I want to somehow **save all rendered results of the page** (not as the form of screenshot, but the form of **rendered result of DOM element**) that we can see on browser, and recover them in local environment without network.

I really don't need to save all the functionalities of the page that interact with other computer. Only the view of the page is needed to be archived.

What I tried to archive youtube.com's home page were,

1. Using beautiful soup to get immediate html sources
2. Using python selenium and chromedriver to get dynamically loaded html sources
3. 2 + downloading all referenced .css, .js, and images from links in html codes to local directory.
4. Pressing ctrl+s on chrome, which downloads html sources and several files. (.js, .css, .jpg, ...)

But all of them did not work correctly.

At first, 4th method seems working, but soon I found out that it downloads initial html source, not a dynamically loaded one.

Is there any known ways to do this kind of stuffs? (archiving currently rendered state of the page)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what I can think of is:
1-use selenium to get the url of your page
2-invoke an external program like "wget" to download the whole page

Comment: With wget <url>, I could not recover dynamically loaded and rendered results.. Actually, it seems like wget gives me only a static html source of the page...